# Android ListView adapter data, mantaining consistency

Tags: android, listview, adapter, consistency

When you create a custom adapter extending `ArrayAdapter<T>`, it has usually the form:

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private List<Item> mData;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> data) {
        super(context, resource, data);
        mData = data;
    }
}
```

The data is initially saved in a private member `mData`, but also the `ArrayAdapter` saves the data in its own member `mObjects`. I am pretty sure those are not actual copies, but references to the same list.
Now, **and this is my question**, if during the *ListView* processing, for some reason, you have to replace your own list with a fresh new List, I think you should also do:

```
mData = new List<Item>();
super.clear();
super.addAll(mData);
```

otherwise there will be no consistency in ListView, and methods like getFilter().filter() will not work.

**Am I correct?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, when you say mData = data; it only copies pointer of the data array, because when you execute that;

```
ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(context, resource, data);
data.clear();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

it changes list. So it keeps pointer of your source array,

Second, I think (not sure) you cannot use filter function of adapter, at least I couldn't use and write my own filter function. I filter elements from sqlite(I  take my elements from database). and use notifyDataSetChanged function of adapter.

Comment: @streetsofboston What would do, in your opinion if instead of `data.clear()` you execute `data=null`? ::: And I apologize in advance, I know this is not a discussion forum, so maybe it is better I mark an aswer and take this issue somwhere where it can be discussed.

Comment: "data = null;" doesn't do anything for the ListAdapter.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. Your `ListAdapter` doesn't make a deep copy of the provided list of `Items`. This means that changing an `Item` instance 'outside' the `ListAdapter` will put the `ListAdapter` in an invalid state.

However, you can 'fix' this by calling `notifyDataSetChanged` on the `ListAdapter`.

```
List<Item> itemList = ....
....
....
ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.somelayout, itemList);
....
```

Now, if you change an item 'outside' the ListAdapter, you can still make your ListAdapter be in sync with the change:

```
itemList.get(idx).changeSomethingInItem("Hello"); // Changes the Item at index 'idx'.
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                   // Notify adapter about this change.
```

Answer (score -1):

you really needn't pretty sure whether it actual copies or not ,just extend BaseAdapter

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand what you're saying. Can you elaborate? ::: Your answer seems like a comment,  not an answer.